# Remove file as part of a commit

Tags: git, commit

Say I have a file system that includes:

```
file1.java
file2.java
file3.java
file4.java
```

And I just finished a commit that has `betterfile.java` that is supposed to replace `file`1,2,3 and 4. So I am about to commit `betterfile.java` and now I have no use for the other files. So how do I delete them from the next commit. How could I remove all of the other files (`file1`, `file2`, etc.) from the commit I'm about to do, but still keep them historically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git rm file1.java file2.java file3.java file4.java
git add betterfile.java
git status # See that the files are removed, and betterfile.java is staged
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a tool like TortoiseGit then just delete the files you don't want, replace with the new file and commit as normal. The files will be marked as 'deleted' and the new file as 'added'.

Answer (score 0):

Change the files to what you want the directory structure to look like by add and deleting files via shell, windows or whatever. Then:

```
git add -A
```

This stages all changes including deletes, additions and modifications.

```
git commit
```

and you're good to go.